# Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll manifest definition issue

Tags: c#, wcf, nuget, sybase, gac

I have two applications, both referencing the Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll (version 2.155.1000.0, which is also in the GAC); one is a WCF service, the other is a test harness.

The WCF service application fails intermittently with the following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient, Version=2.155.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95d94fac46c88e1e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The error *appears* to occur after I've connected to a Sybase database from another application, although this isn't always reproducible.

**Working reference**

```
<Reference Include="Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient, Version=2.155.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95d94fac46c88e1e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>..\packages\Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.2.155.1000.0\lib\net35\Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**Broken reference**

```
<Reference Include="Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient, Version=2.155.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95d94fac46c88e1e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.2.155.1000.0\lib\net35\Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The fact that the sybdrvado20.dll assembly isn't even required by the working example leaves me all the more confused!

Has anyone come across anything like this before?

It's probably worth noting that when I log off and on again, or restart my machine, the problem temporarily goes away and that I've created a NuGet package which contains the Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll (in the .NET 3.5 folder), with the sybdrvado20.dll at the same level as the lib folder.  The same NuGet pacakge is being referenced by both of the applications.

**EDIT**:  I ran Agent Ransack to generate a list of all Sybase.AseNet2.AseClient.dll files on my machine before and after my application breaks and ran the results through a little application which obtains the assembly versions for each file.  I then compared them in Excel and can report that there are no differences between them, other than one missing file in `C:\Windows\assembly\temp\` when run after my application breaks.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. WCF will fail until I do an iisreset and then it's fine. Were you able to get to the bottom of it?